# How to get basic calls, messages and data usage statistics in Windows Phone?

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone

How to get basic calls, messages and data usage statistics in Windows Phone?

I need to get some basic phone usage stats in my app:

- total duration of outgoing calls in last month
- total number of sms messages sent in last month
- total mobile data usage in last month

How can I do that in Windows Phone? Is it even possible?

Comment: I'm afraid you cannot access these statistics in Windows Phone. There is no API for this task.

Comment: some phone carriers have apis to get info like that for a phone number